# SQL query to find duplicates with mismatching another column

Tags: sql, oracle

Table looks like this:

```
col1 | col2
A    | B
A    | B
D    | C
D    | C
E    | F
E    | G
```

what I need, is to extract col1 **E**.
Already tried couple variants of `SELECT DISTINCT` or `SELECT ..., COUNT(*)` with `GROUP BY`, but can't figure it out.

p.s. DBMS is Oracle

Answer (score 2):

Such as this?

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 'A', 'B' from dual union all
  3     select 'A', 'B' from dual union all
  4     select 'D', 'C' from dual union all
  5     select 'D', 'C' from dual union all
  6     select 'E', 'F' from dual union all
  7     select 'E', 'G' from dual
  8    )
  9  select col1
 10  from test
 11  group by col1
 12  having count(distinct col2) > 1;

C
-
E

SQL>
```